# How to hide usercontrol and main form c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

how to hide user control and main form. The case is like this,
I have two form and one UserControl. Main form and form registers, and UserControl inside the main form. Inside the UserControl there are two buttons, create and delete. When I press the create button, then UserControl and main form hidden and form register show. I've try, but only hidden UserControl.

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: Event to main window to tell it to hide.

Comment: Why hide the UserControl on the MainForm if you are wanting to hide the MainForm?  Odd problem.  Show your code.

Answer (score -1):

Here is MSDN reference to hiding controls [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var registerForm = new Register();//Create instance of register form

        this.Hide();//To hide main form

        registerForm.Show();//To show register form

        userControl.Hide();//To hide user control
       //but do not need to hide usercontrol because when form will hide its automatically hide
    }
```